# XMPP API for Google App Engine connection failure

Tags: xmpp, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, openfire

I have failed completely to get the App Engine XMPP API in an app engine app to talk to an external XMPP Openfire server running on an instance on Compute Engine. I have equally failed to connect with the app engine app from a free jabber server (jabber.at). In both cases the error message returns that the remote server cannot be found, or not found on port 5269. Yet a ncat scan show that 5269 is open on the app engine app.

I have read the Google tutorial, where it says: "The basic sequence of events will go like this: * A user adds crowdguru@appspot.com to their buddy list in Google Talk, or another XMPP client. * The user asks the Amazing Crowd Guru a question, by typing "/tellme Does a duck's quack echo? etc."

I have added all variants of names to roster/buddy lists and nothing happens. And I have checked the addresses for both appspot and appspotchat, they are as prescribed. In both cases I have no trouble using the XMPP servers as normal IM servers independently of App Engine.

Is the XMPP API still working? If so, is there some currently working example java code available anywhere? Is there a better more detailed tutorial or other information available than what is provided on the Google App Engine site at the moment? ( I mean, Python and Java fragments, but only a Python complete example. Why? And 'user adds crowdguru@appspot.com to their buddy list' is less than helpful. No other settings or steps required? Really? )

Any help appreciated. I desire to setup a simple IM or chat function on my app. 
May 10, 2015

Comment: The doc is quite detailed, and I'd recommend you read it thoroughly, as well as understand the XMPP protocol, if you want to implement such a thing. Here's the [Java source](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/demos/crowdguru/#crowdguru) if you're interested, I tracked it down with a google search. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. Finally, perhaps you could include some more technical information in your reply, as despite describing that it "doesn't work", there's not a lot to work with for anybody trying to help :) Have a nice day!

Comment: The doc for reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp

Answer (score 1):

It may be worthwhile noting that the XMPP API will be permanently disabled on October 31, 2017: [XMPP API Turndown](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/xmpp).

Please see Alternatives to the XMPP API for information on how to replicate functionality with other Google Cloud Platform products. For example, developers using the API for direct messaging with XMPP clients can easily build a similar service using virtual machines on Google Compute Engine. For developers using XMPP for realtime data synchronization, we recommend using the Firebase Realtime Database, which is explicitly designed for this purpose.